# PERL: Displaying values through regular expressions not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner in Perl. I want to display the Tax Types of different countries for my new website in Perl.  Based on the respective countries from the API I use, I get all the Tax Types in Uppercase letters. I don’t want all in uppercase letters
I have tried the following regular expression. Following is the code:

```
my $key = <input>;

my $value = $key =~ /^(\w\w\w? \w)(.+)$/ ? $1 . lc $2 : ucfirst lc $key;

print $value;
```

Here are inputs and outputs that I get from the above code:

```
1: Input: ‘AUSTRALIA GST’

Output: ‘Australia gst’


2. Input: ‘AZ COUNTY TAX’

Output: ‘AZ County tax’


3. Input: ‘NEW ZEALAND GST’

Output: ‘NEW Zealand gst’


4. Input: ‘VAT’

Output: ‘Vat’
```

I want the following outputs for the respective inputs from the same single code:

```
1: Input: ‘AUSTRALIA GST’

Output: ‘Australia GST’


2. Input: ‘AZ COUNTY TAX’

Output: ‘AZ County Tax’


3. Input: ‘NEW ZEALAND GST’

Output: ‘New Zealand GST’


4. Input: ‘VAT’

Output: ‘VAT’
```

Can anyone please help as to how to dynamically fix this with regular expression in PERL ?

Comment: And this neatly demonstrates why I said on your last version of this question that I didn't care what the data is. The fact that this is about tax is completely irrelevant. The import thing is that you have some words that are converted using `ucfirst lc` and some that are left as upper case. In Daxim's answer, he has created an `%ignore` hash that encodes that information. That is what we needed to know in order to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @DaveCross and agreed

Comment: @DaveCross, If I have only one word like VAT, IGST, SGST, CGST, CPF and not multiple words, I don't want to add that in an array. Instead directly show that in the output like it was in the word. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use 5.016;

sub maybe_ucfirst {
    my ($word) = @_;
    my %ignore = map { $_ => undef } qw(GST AZ VAT);
    return exists $ignore{$word} ? $word : ucfirst fc $word;
}

my @inputs = ('AUSTRALIA GST', 'AZ COUNTY TAX', 'NEW ZEALAND GST', 'VAT');
for my $s (@inputs) {
    $s =~ s/(\w+)/maybe_ucfirst($1)/eg;
    say $s;
}
__END__
Australia GST
AZ County Tax
New Zealand GST
VAT
```

Comment: If I have only one word like VAT, IGST, SGST, CGST, CPF and not multiple words, I don't want to add that in an array. Instead directly show that in the output. Is that possible ?

Comment: Oh, may I know how ?

Comment: Sure, will do that, thank you. Since one person can post a question every 90 minutes, so I asked if its possible here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503932/perl-skip-the-values-in-array-and-loop-and-directly-show-in-output